# Outline doesn't wrap the div completely when there are multiple divs side by side in SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have four divs (tabs) and I am trying to add an outline to the tab, but the outline doesn't wrap the whole div. I think the border here on the tabs are causing it. What is the right approach to add an outline to the div? 
Code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="main-style">Random</div>
<div class="styling active1">Btn 1</div>
<div class="styling active2">Btn 2</div>
<div class="styling active3">Btn 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-style,.styling {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 36px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.styling {
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
 }

.over {
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.active1').addClass('over'); // the outline doesn't wrap the whole button.
//$('.active3').addClass('over'); the outline wraps the whole button
```

Here is the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euw6Lpot/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hidden by the next tab. Add `position: relative`, and `z-index: 1` to the `.over` tab to make it appear above the next tab:

```js
$('.active1').addClass('over'); // the outline doesn't wrap the whole button.
```

```css
.main-style,
.styling {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 36px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.styling {
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
}

.styling:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.over {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-style">Random</div>
<div class="styling active1">Btn 1</div>
<div class="styling active2">Btn 2</div>
<div class="styling active3">Btn 3</div>
```

Comment: Wow. that was so quick. Thank you so much :)